# Using set -e (errexit) with block of commands and executing another on fail of that block (SC2181)

Tags: error-handling, exit-status, shell-builtin, set

I just found out about `set -e` as I was searching for an answer to "how to run many commands (without `&&`) and immediately stop on non-zero exit code of any of them?". The `set -e` was good enough for me until I discovered that

```bash
(set -e; false; echo here) || echo error
```

does produce `here` instead of `error`. But as I quickly found a solution of a new problem:

```bash
(set -e; false; echo here); [ $? -ne 0 ] && echo error
```

I also bumped to an old problem with `$?` instead of `if cmd` ([SC2181](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2181)).

Now I have a new question: do I just ignore the SC2181 error, or is there a proper way to make it work?

I also thought about `trap` but I don't know if `set -e` produces any signal at all.

---

Note that

```bash
if ! (set -e; false; echo here); then
  echo error
fi
```

also prints `here` instead of `error`. From [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2181) website:

> Apart from the redundancy, there are other reasons to avoid this pattern:
>
> - [...]
> - Scripts that run or are called with `set -e` aka `errexit` will exit immediately if the command fails, even though they're followed by a clause that handles failure.

Which means that `if` statement is immune to `errexit` or disables it.

Also note that absence of `()` or its substitution to `{}` will stop execution of next commands, including error checking command.

---

P.S. I want to try to have as fewer ShellCheck errors in my scripts as possible (which are almost always indicate that the script is not optimized or have bugs). In addition, executing a lot of commands with appened `&&` operator IMHO decreases code readability and editability, therefore I want to find a cleaner solution (at least for that specific block of commands in `()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always cheat  and do something like:

```bash
last_block_failed() { return "$(( ! $? ))"; }
```

```bash
(set -o errexit
...
)
if last_block_failed; then
  echo>&2 error
fi
```

Or variants like:

```bash
last_block_failed() (( ! $? ))
last_block_failed() { [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; }
last_block_failed() [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
```

Note that in bash (contrary to the Bourne shell and most other Bourne-like shells which allow any command), function bodies have to be *compound* commands, so <strike>`last_block_failed() [ "$?" -ne 0 ]`</strike> won't work. The commands group (`{ ...; }`), `((...))` and `[[ ... ]]` are all *compound commands*.

Comment: Since this is just `[ $? -ne 0 ]` in disguise, I will stick with a simplified version: `last_block_failed() { [ $? -ne 0 ];}`. ShellCheck doesn't complain this way. Thanks for the solution (it also improves readability even further).

Comment: @Andrew15_5, ShellCheck should complain about the missing quotes in there which make it subject to $IFS-splitting. Or write it `last_block_failed() [[ $? -ne 0 ]]`  or `last_block_failed() (( $? != 0 ))` Or `last_block_failed() (( !  $? ))`

Comment: It doesn't complain because `$?` stores the exit code of a previous command, which implies that `$?` is a number and doesn't have spaces or newlines (I don't know who would assign a digit to IFS). Hence, it's safe to use it without quotes. And `[ <> -ne 0 ]` is a perfectly valid command which is another form of `test <> -ne 0` (it returns 0 if the expression is true and 1 if false).

Comment: @Andrew15_5, `[ $? -ne 0 ]` in another language would be written `equal(glob(split($?)), 0)` which makes no sense. `[ "$?" -ne 0 ]` would be `equal($?, 0)` which makes sense. See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)